# Maclaurin/Laurent series of a complex log

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

I've been asked to find the Maclaurin series of
\begin{equation}
\text{Log}(1+2z)
\end{equation}
Which I've done, and found to be $2z-2z^2+\frac{8z^3}{3}...$,

I'm now told 'hence find the first three terms about $z=0$ of the function
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{z^2\text{Log}(1+2z)}
\end{equation}

I see the second function is the reciprocal of the first multiplied by $\frac{1}{z^2}$ but I'm not sure how their series are related?

Comment: Do you know how to get the Laurent series of $1/f(z)$?

Comment: @PeterForeman I don't think so? I'll look through my notes

Comment: @PeterForeman IIRC, it's expansion is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-z)^n$?

Comment: The second function is not the first multiplied by $1/z^2$. It is the *reciprocal* of the first multiplied by $1/z^2$.

Comment: @DougM my question states it wants expansion about singular point $z=0$, valid near $z=0$, and that I should then find the residue at $z=0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{z^2\text{Log}(1+2z)} = \frac 1{z^2} \cdot \frac 1{2z-2z^2+\frac{8z^3}{3}\ldots}
 = \frac 1{2z^3} \cdot \frac 1{1-(z-\frac{4z^2}{3}\ldots)}
\end{equation}
Expand using $\frac 1{1-z}=1+z+z^2+\ldots$.

The result will have negative powers, which is normal and part of a *Laurent series*.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{{z^2 \log (1 + 2z)}} & = \frac{1}{{2z^3 }}\frac{{2z}}{{\log (1 + 2z)}} = \frac{1}{{2z^3 }}\frac{{2z}}{{2z - 2z^2  + \frac{{8z^3 }}{3} -  \cdots }} = \frac{1}{{2z^3 }}\frac{1}{{1 - z + \frac{{4z^2 }}{3} -  \cdots }} \\ & = \frac{1}{{2z^3 }}\left( {1 - \left( { - z + \frac{{4z^2 }}{3} -  \cdots } \right) + \left( { - z + \frac{{4z^2 }}{3} -  \cdots } \right)^2  -  \cdots } \right) =  \cdots .
\end{align*}